# Android spinner why can't I display drop down like a normal human?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm working on a card game and I want to show a dialog box prompting the user to select a suit. I make the dialog and set the layout. As soon as I try to populate the spinner using setadapter my app spasms out a white screen comes and it reloads from the beginning. Here is the code below.

```
    private void showChooseSuitDialog(){
        final Dialog chooseSuitDialog = new Dialog(myContext);
        chooseSuitDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        chooseSuitDialog.setContentView(R.layout.choose_suit_dialog);
        final Spinner suitSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.suitSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(myContext, R.array.suits, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        suitSpinner.setAdapter(adapter); // **** This is where it blows up ****
//        Button okButton = (Button) chooseSuitDialog.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
//        okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                validSuit = (suitSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()+1) * 100;
//                String suitText = "";
//                if(validSuit == 100){
//                    suitText = "Diamonds";
//                }else if(validSuit == 200){
//                    suitText = "Clubs";
//                }else if(validSuit == 300) {
//                    suitText = "Hearts";
//                }else {
//                    suitText = "Spades";
//                }
//                chooseSuitDialog.dismiss();
//                Toast.makeText(myContext, "You chose " + suitText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//        });
```

Comment: please share your choose_suit_dialog.xml

Comment: and also the definition of the `suits` array.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your spinner is in the activity (or fragment), not in the dialog.

Create a DialogFragment for the card chooser and add the spinner to the layout of that dialog fragment. Pass the result back to the activity (or fragment) upon selection.